# ImportError: cannot import name 'load_workbook'

Tags: python-3.x, pycharm

```
#! python3
    # readcensusExcel.py - Tabulates population and number of census tracts for
    # each county

    import openpyxl, pprint

    print('Opening excel file...')
    wb = openpyxl.load_workbook('censuspopdata.xlsx')
    sheet = wb.get_sheet_by_name('Sheet1')

C:\Python34\python.exe C:/Users/ohmiw/PycharmProjects/myproject/readCeususExcel.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
Ask again later
  File "C:/Users/ohmiw/PycharmProjects/myproject/readCeususExcel.py", line 5, in <module>
It is certain
    import openpyxl, pprint
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\__init__.py", line 30, in <module>
    from openpyxl.reader.excel import load_workbook
ImportError: cannot import name 'load_workbook'

Process finished with exit code 1
```

I really have no idea about how to handle this... I'm a beginner with Python. I wrote code with openpyxl.load_workbook() as usual, but it says, ImportError: cannot import name 'load_workbook'. Someone, please help me with this.